# Check boxes in Java Control Panel Disabled

Tags: windows-7, java, java-web-start

I am trying to find out why a Java Web Start application on a cistomer's Windows 7 notebook is crashing.

Network configuration works fine: a test JWS app limited to network access succeeds on that machine.

I enabled logging and tracing but I was not able to spot a cause for the crash.

The only strange bit I noticed so far is that the last two options of
the dialog for deleting files from the JWS cache were grayed out.

(See the Temporary Files Settings dialog in the Java control panel).

Here is how that dialog usually looks like:

[image: This is the normal dialog]

I suspect that Java usage on that machine is restricted by some administration feature and that this interference also is responsible for the unexpected crashes of the JWS client application.

I had a session with an administrator earlier, when figuring out the network settings, and there the JWS client ran fine.

**Question:** Does anyone know what kind of administrative settings would lead to a disabling of check boxes in that Java control panel dialog for a user?

Comment: Did you try running the Java Control Panel as an Administrator?

Comment: Are you an Administrator on this machine?  Is this machine connected to an Active Domain?  Are you an Administrator on the domain if thats the case?  Do you have authorization to change the group policy if its required to be done?

Comment: @DavidPostill I searched for the control panel and got a right mouse button context menu entry for running it as administrator, alas it did not open.

Comment: If you are. It an Administrator then asked somebody that is

Comment: As a normal user you will not be able to solve this problem.  Which means your question cannot be answered, since you don't have the required permissions, to implement any potental fix.

Comment: @Ramhound I work together with one of administrators of the customer. He can change the permissions. Alas he has no idea yet what to change.

Comment: So it seems the administrator should be the one asking this question.  You don't even know if your connected to an Active Domain, which means, your not familar with any of the things you will be required to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The machine was inspected by one of the customer's administrators. His impression was that the machine went through various configurations which resulted in an unexpected state. He re-installed and now everything works fine.

Comment: Glad to hear that worked for you. Don't forget to mark your answer as 'accepted' to mark your question as closed.